# Fixing the offset for jQuery ScrollTo and jQuery Waypoints to work correctly

Tags: jquery, scrollto, jquery-waypoints

I am using two jQuery plugins on my site to accomplish two things:

1. [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) - So that as I scroll down the page and get to each section, the black bar underneath the appropriate menu link turns white:

   [image]

   2. [jQuery ScrollTo](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) - I am using this to smooth scroll between sections when you click one of the main menu links.

My problem is that as I scroll down the page manually, the appropriate selected class gets added to the main menu link (to turn the bar underneath white as shown above) via Waypoints as it should.  But when I click the actual link on the main menu, it does not work until I scroll down a little further manually.  There are some offset options for both scripts that I believe can make it work correctly, but I can't figure it out.  I setup a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/j5Guz/).  Here's my current jquery:

```
$(function() {                    
  var sections = $('section');
  var navigation_links = $('nav a');
  sections.waypoint({
    handler: function(event, direction) {
        var active_section;
        active_section = $(this);
        if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();
        var active_link = $('nav a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');
        navigation_links.removeClass("selected");
        active_link.addClass("selected");
    },
    offset: '35%'
  });

    navigation_links.click( function(event) {
      $.scrollTo(
        $(this).attr("href"),
        {
          duration: 500,
          offset: { 'left':0, 'top':-0.15*$(window).height() }
        }
      );
    });

});
```

Comment: May not matter, but `handler: function(event, direction)` is the old 1.x handler signature, but your fiddle is using Waypoints 2.0.2, which just uses: `handler: function(direction)`.

Answer (score 0):

the jsFiddle does not seem to be fully working (the navbar is not kept in view when scrolling down) but I've had this exact same problem, where the navbar transitions work with manual scrolling, but when clicked, don't quite hit the right position.

The solution for me was to use Firebug to inspect the navbar element, then look at the `Layout` tab which will show the exact total pixel height of the navbar, including padding and margin.  Then you can set the `offset` to match that total pixel height.  e.g. if the navbar height is 85 pixels, then in the setup I have,

```
<body id="the-page" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="85" data-spy="scroll">
```

Here, once `data-offset` is correct, then clicking on a navbar link will get to the right location on the page, as well as change the highlighted section in the navbar.